# Is it possible to use Perl's Getopt::Std in 2 packages?

Tags: perl, getopt

[perl script]
perl_script.pl -b "HELLO" -v

```
use package1;
use package2;

my $argb = GetPackage1Option;
my $argv = GetPackage2Option;

print "$argb\n";                                # Print -b argument
print "v is found!\n" if ( GetPackage2Option ); # Print
```

[package1.pm]

```
use Getopt::Std;
require Exporter;
@ISA = qw(Exporter);
@EXPORT = qw( GetPackage1Option );

sub GetPackage1Option {

    getopt('b');
    our ($opt_b);

    my $argb = $opt_b || '';

    return $argb;
}
```

[package2.pm]

```
use Getopt::Std;
require Exporter;
@ISA = qw(Exporter);
@EXPORT = qw( GetPackage2Option );

sub GetPackage2Option {

    my $bool = 0;
    my %opt;
    getopts('v', \%opt);

    return ( defined $optHash{v} ) ? $optHash{v} : $bool;
}
```

I am calling 2 functions from 2 separate packages and each function uses a different option.

I tried this but I am only getting the option for -b. The -v option works if I remove the functions that use -b.

Apologies this only sort of a summary of my original code.

Please let me know if my question is confusing. Thanks :)

Comment: Conceptually, your code is a fragile mess with no foundation: There *is* a single set of command line arguments passed to your program. It does not make sense to keep processing `@ARGV` over and over in different parts. Your modules should not be doing their `@ARGV` processing. That said,  you *could* make a copy of `@ARGV` ... But I would implore you to fix your design instead.

Comment: I agree with Sinan. You should put the command line argument handling into your program, and map the arguments so each module can get what it wants. Alternatively you can give each module a functionality that lets them _define_ an interface for the command line, and then you can have your program use that to compile a full list of arguments and parse them.

Answer (score 2):

`Getopt::Std` operates on and "consumes" the global `@ARGV` array. To run `getopt` or `getopts` multiple times, you could use `local` to make a temporary copy of `@ARGV`.

```
sub GetPackage1Option {
    local @ARGV = @ARGV;
    getopt('b');
    our ($opt_b);    
    my $argb = $opt_b || '';    
    return $argb;
}        # end of scope, original @ARGV restored
```

Though like Sinan and simbabque say, this is an unorthodox design that you should probably reconsider.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way out of the conundrum is for command line argument parsing to happen at the entry point of your program where the values of the arguments can be saved in a hash, where you can provide default values for those not specified on the command line etc. Then, you can decide how to communicate the values each module is interested in (e.g. package variables or constructor arguments).

I would strongly recommend against this kind of action at a distance, but here's how one might go about automating the setting of values of package variables in different modules in response to values given on the command line. Each package is responsible for declaring the command line switches in which it is interested.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

package X;

our @PACKAGE_OPTS = qw( v x: );

our ($OPT_V, $OPT_X);

sub func {
    print "$OPT_V\t$OPT_X\n";
}

package Y;

our @PACKAGE_OPTS = qw( t y: z);

our ($OPT_T, $OPT_Y, $OPT_Z);

sub func {
    print join("\t", $OPT_T, $OPT_Y, $OPT_Z), "\n";
}

package main;

use Getopt::Std;

main();

sub main {
    init_opts(qw( X Y ));
    X::func();
    Y::func();
}

sub init_opts {
    my %opts;
    my $opt_string;
    my %opt_to_package;

    for my $pkg ( @_ ) {
        my @opts = eval "\@${pkg}::PACKAGE_OPTS";
        $opt_string .= join '', @opts;

        for my $opt ( @opts ) {
            (my $var = $opt) =~ s/[^A-Za-z]+//g;
            $opts{$var} = '-not provided-';
            $opt_to_package{$var} = $pkg;
        }
    }

    getopts($opt_string, \%opts);

    for my $opt (keys %opts) {
        my $pkg = $opt_to_package{$opt};
        my $var = 'OPT_' . uc $opt;
        eval "\$${pkg}::${var} = \$opts{\$opt}"
    }

    return;
}
```

Output:

```
C:\...\Temp> perl tt.pl -zvx a -y b
1       a
-not provided-  b       1
```